# Why does Spring Boot CORS configuration change server responses?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

By enabling [CORS configuration in Spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/), you can get 403 responses when using not allowed methods or not allowed origins. But why? The CORS configuration should tell the browser how to behave when a cross origin request is triggered. This behaviour may block the request at the browser level, not even reaching the server. So why Spring makes the server return 403? If the server got the request, it should respond with the requested resource. As explained in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), CORS security should be handled by the browser, not the server.

Is there a way to make Spring NOT return 403 on these cases? Just respond with the information needed by the browser to decide whether or not allow the request.

Comment: It would help to clients that are not frontend clients, so they don't have to deal with CORS. CORS tells the browser whether or not to share the response. What's the point of changing the response then?

Comment: But I'd like to enable CORS to protect my application from browser clients, and be able to send basic requests from my browser to see that the app is working fine. I can't do that because my browser's Origin is not allowed.